How to Add Comments to SharePoint List Items Using Power Automate?
Problem Statement:
I am trying to add comments to a SharePoint list item using Power Automate. For this, I used the "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint" action. However, my flow fails with the following error:
Action 'Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint-copy' failed: {"odata.error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ResourceNotFoundException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Cannot find resource for the request Commnets."}}

Steps I Took:

I created a flow in Power Automate.
I added a "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint" action with the following settings:


Site Address: <Your Site URL>
Method: POST
Uri: _api/web/lists/getbytitle('Project Tracker')/items(<Item ID>)/Comments
Headers:
Content-Type: application/json
Body

{
    "text": "This is a comment."
}

The error suggests that the resource "Commnets" cannot be found.
I double-checked my endpoint URL, but the issue persists.

What am I doing wrong?
Is there a different API endpoint I should use for adding comments to SharePoint list items?
Are there any specific permissions required for this action?


I am working with a modern SharePoint Online list named "Project Tracker."

I have full control permissions on the list.


Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Check your spelling for "comments".

After investigating, I discovered the issue was caused by a typo in the endpoint URL. I had written Commnets instead of Comments. Correcting the typo resolved the issue.
Here’s the corrected configuration that worked for me:
HTTP Request Configuration
Method: POST
Endpoint:
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Project Tracker')/items('ItemID')/Comments

Headers:
{
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
   
}

Body:
{
    "text": "This is a new item."
}

I hope this helps anyone facing a similar issue! If you have any further questions or suggestions, feel free to share them in the comments below. 
